# How To count Number of queues in ACTIVEMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jmx

I am trying to create an application which keeps on checking the number of queues up and running in activemq.
And Any way to check whether queue's are working or not i.e. if corrupted and not able to process messages.
Kindly suggest how to do it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // get the initial context
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();

        // lookup the queue object
        Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("queue/queue0");

        // lookup the queue connection factory
        QueueConnectionFactory connFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.
            lookup("queue/connectionFactory");

        // create a queue connection
        QueueConnection queueConn = connFactory.createQueueConnection();

        // create a queue session
        QueueSession queueSession = queueConn.createQueueSession(false,
            Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // create a queue browser
        QueueBrowser queueBrowser = queueSession.createBrowser(queue);

        // start the connection
        queueConn.start();

        // browse the messages
        Enumeration e = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
        int numMsgs = 0;

        // count number of messages
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            Message message = (Message) e.nextElement();
            numMsgs++;
        }

        System.out.println(queue + " has " + numMsgs + " messages");

        // close the queue connection
        queueConn.close();
    }
```

Comment: Be aware that a message browser does not always give all messages on queue. By default, ActiveMQ has a browse limit of 400 messages. So this answer cannot distinguish between 400 and 100 000 messages. Also, it's very slow for large messages since it requires that you download them all just to count them.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for stats using the [statistics plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html) on the broker and the plain JMS api. I.e. to count the number of messages on FOO.BAR, send an empty message to `ActiveMQ.Statistics.Destination.TEST.FOO` and specify the replyTo header. In the response message, which is of typ MapMessage, you can find the message counter.

Another way is to browse only the first message of the queue using a simple queue browser (similar to the way praveen_programmer suggests) and check the timestamp of that message. If it's older than some threshold, you might have a problem with that consumer. I.e. no messages has been processed in the last hour/minute/day.

Yet another way is to use [JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html), or preferably the [jolokia REST/HTTP management api](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html).

Just query the destination using http and you get a queue depth back:
To query the queue "q" on localhost, use the following api (you need to supply the user/password for the web console):
http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=q

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Advisory messages.  You need to enable them in your config , but you can get a lot of useful about your current activemq instances info through simple JMS messaging. http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html I was using them to highlight slow producer and consumer scenarios.